# virsh support for docker

Tags: docker, libvirt, virsh

Is there any libvirt support for docker?
How to access docker containers using virsh tool or libvirt?
Docker uses linux lxc, there is a libvirt support for lxc, But I am unable to access containers created by docker using `virsh -c lxc:///`

Comment: I am curious about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

First of all docker doesn't use lxc: they have their own containers implementation with libcontainer (donated as OCI runc FWICT).

Libvirt lxc driver is another container implementation, that is different from the one of the LXC project.

So the answer to your question is: no there is no way to access your docker containers with libvirt / virsh / virt-manager.